# Community VFP Mobile Responsiveness issue

Tags: visualforce

So I have built out a custom VFP that we are using for our Community.  Now, when I 'decrease' the browser to a mobile size, it resizes and goes into our Mobile-friendly mode.  However, when I open it on my phone it is NOT doing that Mobile-friendly responsiveness.  Is this an issue that others have come across, is this community related?  Or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any issues with responsive design with Visualforce in Communities.  There are a number of developerforce articles and blogs that provide guidance on how to design a page to support different frameworks.  Here are two:

- https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/01/responsive-design-javascript-html5-css-visualforce.html
- https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Responsive_Design_with_Twitter_Bootstrap_and_Visualforce

Some things in particular you could check would be:

1. Have you set the viewport metatag in the `<head>`:

   `<meta name="viewport” content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0”></meta>`
2. Have you set the doctype to html5 and removed the various salesforce added styles in the `<apex:page>` tag?

   `<apex:page showheader="false" sidebar="false" standardstylesheets="false" doctype="html-5.0">`

Comment: You are the man!!!  it was the meta code :)